# Why it would create indexoutofbounds error and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, for-loop, primes

I'm just trying to write write a small program that lists all the prime numbers between 10 and 1000, but it keeps reporting errors (Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at PrimeFinder.main), I am not sure where I do wrong.

```
  class PrimeFinder {

    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int x=2; x<=(int)Math.sqrt(n); x++) {
            if (n%x == 0) {
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("usage: java PrimeFinder <max-range>");
            return;
        }

        int maxRange = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i=2; i > 10 && i < 1000; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The if-statement in main should be ``if (args.length != 1) { ... }``

Comment: Now it prints only the "usage..." statement, I wonder how I could make it to list all the prime numbers intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to,

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("usage: java PrimeFinder <max-range>");
    return;
}
```

you are not expecting any user inputs to the program. If there are any user inputs, then simply your program will exit and print the Log in the console. If there are no user inputs then flow will continue and then with the line,

```
int maxRange = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

you are evaluating `args[]` which is actually empty. So it will throw the `IndexOutOfBound` error

Simply remove the following lines from the code, if you don't need to perform any validation on user inputs (at least you are not doing anything useful with the `maxRange` in the code),

```
/*
if (args.length > 0) {
        System.out.println("usage: java PrimeFinder <max-range>");
        return;
    }

int maxRange = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
*/
```

or else correct the logic in there.

ex:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("usage: java PrimeFinder <max-range>");
    return;
}
```

and the for loop in main should be corrected as follows,

```
for (int i=11; i > 10 && i < 1000; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the elaboration, but it seems it still prints nothing, no error reporting either.

Comment: @dfgfgg Updated the asnwer.

Comment: Ohhh gosh, that was moronic of me... Thanks!